# Как использовать VK API в Xamarin?

Tags: android, c#, vkontakte-api, xamarin

Здравствуйте! Делаю приложение на Android с использованием Xamarin. Нужно сделать авторизацию через вк. На хабре нашел статью о том, как можно сделать авторизацию через вк используя Xamarin.Auth: https://habrahabr.ru/post/216553/
Попробовал сделать так же, но это не то, что мне нужно.

Как сделать так, чтобы мое приложение могло авторизовываться через вк, при этом оно смотрело установлен ли вк на телефоне, и если да, то просто запрашивала разрешение?

P.S. Исходников нет так ка я тупо скопировал код из той статьи.
P.P.S. Я новенький в Xamarin, поэтому в нем еще слабо разбираюсь.

Comment: если вы новенький в Xamarin, может еще не поздно бросить эту хлипкую дорожку, и перейти на **темную сторону** (Java)?

Comment: @metalurgus , хаха:D ответ супер! Проект на Xamarin, так как это необходимо заказчику, поэтому некуда деваться.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/323296/ Тут посмотрите. Сам пока не про бывал поэтому описывать не буду